# Model fields not recognized from the Intellisense

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, phpstorm

So, in the model I've listed the `fillable` and `hidden` fields, and then when I access fields on the object of that model, they get highlighted as `Field 'some_field' not found in class ...`. If I add phpDoc to it as follows:

```
/** @var Trip $trip */
$trip->driver = ...
```

the field is being highlighted. If I write

```
/** @var object $trip */
$trip->driver = ...
```

it's not highlighted, but that's just not right. Everything works fine, but it just looks bad in the IDE, and the highlighting is annoying.

Then I decided to simply declare variables in the model class, for every field, so that they're recognized, but then the fields always hold `NULL`, when I access them on the object.

Anyone has a solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use PhpStorm you can write it above your model class as a comment.

`/**
 * App\User
 *
 * @property string $username
 */`

You can also use a composer package called laravel-ide-helper here you have the link

https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

You can use some simple commands to generate helper files and it will provide you with code completion.